# Sort products by category field value

Tags: ordering, queries, order, products

All of my products have a category field called stateCat. These state categories have a field called stateImportance. This is because some states are more important than others and I want to sort the products based on that stateImportance number. I have no idea how to do this.

This is what I've tried:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.order('stateCat.stateImportance asc').type('coins').limit(null) %}
```

This doesn't seem to work, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: "This is because some states are more important than others". For example, any state is greater than Florida.

Comment: (Really hope you're not from Florida)

Comment: Im not from the US and I'm making a website with coins that are 200-300 years old. Coins from certain states in The Netherlands have more value than others. These have to be on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work out of the box with Craft as the category field is a relation field.

However you should be able to use [SuperSort](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort) plugin.

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type('coins').limit(null) %}
{% set orderedProducts = products | supersort('sortAs', '{stateCat.first.stateImportance}' %}
```